# Filter rows which has multiple conditions

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing

I'm trying to generate new csv file from an existing csv file of 3.2 GB with `,` as delimiter. However, the output which I'm getting is a 0B csv file.

Condition is to Filter all the tweets with `lang = ‘en’` which contain the term ‘Corona’ or ‘Covid’ and `verified users = True` and `retweet_count` is greater than or equal to 20

Below are column names:

```
     1  status_id
     2  user_id
     3  created_at
     4  screen_name
     5  text
     6  source
     7  reply_to_status_id
     8  reply_to_user_id
     9  reply_to_screen_name
    10  is_quote
    11  is_retweet
    12  favourites_count
    13  retweet_count
    14  country_code
    15  place_full_name
    16  place_type
    17  followers_count
    18  friends_count
    19  account_lang
    20  account_created_at
    21  verified
    22  lang
```

Below is the code I tried:

```
grep 'Corona' | 'Covid' > awk -F',' '$22=='en' && $13>=20 && $>21 == True {print,}' > output.csv
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming column 5 is the tweet text, the following `awk` command should help

```
awk -F',' '$5 ~ /Corona|Covid/ && $22=="en" && $13>=20 && $21=="True"' > output.csv
```

To explain:

- `$5 ~ /Corona|Covid/` : checks if column 5 contains `Corona` OR `Covid`. Use `$5 ~ /[Cc]orona|[Cc]ovid/` to ignore the case of the initial character in each word.
- All other conditions should be straight-forward to understand.
- The combined boolean test will evaluate to `0` (=false) or `1` (=true), and `awk` interprets any `0` or `1` outside of a `{ ... }` rule as "don't print this line" or "print this line", respectively.